# Counting symmetric grid chains

Tags: code-golf, geometry, combinatorics, grid

## Notation and definitions

Let \$[n] = \{1, 2, ..., n\}\$ denote the set of the first \$n\$ positive integers.

A [polygonal chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_chain) is a collection of connected line segments.

The *corner set* of a polygonal chain is a collection of points which are the endpoints of one or more of the line segments of the chain.

## Challenge

The goal of this challenge is to write a program that takes two integers, \$n\$ and \$m\$ and computes the number of non-self-intersecting polygonal chains with corner set in \$[n] \times [m]\$ that hit every point in \$[n] \times [m]\$ and are stable under \$180^\circ\$ rotation. You should count these shapes up to the symmetries of the rectangle or square.

Note: In particular, a polygon is considered to be self-intersecting.

## Example

For example, for \$n=m=3\$, there are six polygonal chains that hit all nine points in \$[3] \times [3]\$ and are the same after a half-turn:

[image: 3 X 3 polygonal chains]

#### Table of small values

```
 n | m | f(n,m)
---+---+-------
 1 | 2 | 1
 1 | 3 | 1
 2 | 1 | 1
 2 | 2 | 1
 2 | 3 | 5
 2 | 4 | 11
 2 | 5 | 23
 3 | 1 | 1
 3 | 2 | 5
 3 | 3 | 6
 3 | 4 | 82
```

## Scoring

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so shortest code wins.

Comment: You say "stable under rotation by 180 degrees", but your 3x3 example seems to be stable on all 90-degree multiple rotations and reflections. Can you clarify, and give us a detailed non-square example?

Comment: Do you have any test cases for larger values?

Comment: Consider your first example for 3x3; call that `A`. Now imagine the vertical reflection of that example; call that `A'`. Why is `A'` not also shown as one of the possible polygonal chains to be counted? Surely it is exactly as "stable" as `A` under the action of rotation through 180-degrees; and yet it is not identical to `A`. Why is it not counted separately?

Comment: I misunderstood your earlier comment. This challenge has you count *essentially different* configurations: “You should count these shapes up to the symmetries of the rectangle or square.”

Comment: So you are special casing squares, right?  I mean, the algorithm for a square will be essentially different from that for an oblong rectangle.

Comment: I think f(2,2)=2. There's an open chain shaped like an N and a closed chain shaped like a square.

Comment: I'd imagine that the reason that the closed-square on a 2*2 is not counted is that it is considered to be "self-intersecting" (albeit only at a node)

Comment: @Peter, this is a good question and Jonathan gives the correct answer. This challenge doesn’t count polygons because it considers them self-intersecting.

Comment: If a closed chain is self-intersecting then so is every open chain with more than one segment. If you want to count only open chains then I think you have to state it explicitly in the question in those terms.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, I don't see it that way, but I'll edit the problem to disambiguate.

Comment: @L.F., the way that I've implemented my code doesn't treat the squares as special cases—but it's true that in principle you have to check eight symmetries of the square, but only four symmetries of a rectangle.

Comment: @PeterKagey I think OP means "exactly \$(nm - 2)\$ intersections"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + [SymPy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html), <sub><s>480</s></sub> <sub><s>455</s></sub> 452 bytes

```python
lambda w,h:len({min(I(D(H(V(x)))for x in o)for H,V,D in Q((lambda p:(w+~p[0],p[1]),I),(lambda p:(p[0],h+~p[1]),I),(lambda p:p[::-1],I)))for o in permutations(Q(range(w),range(h)))for s in[[*zip(o,o[1:])]]if any(x-~X-w|y+Y-h+1for(x,y),(X,Y)in zip(o,o[::-1]))+any(gcd(x-X,y-Y)>1for(x,y),(X,Y)in s)+any((len({*u,*v})>3)*intersection(S(*u),S(*v))for u,v in Q(s,s))<1})
from math import*
from sympy import*
from itertools import*
Q=product
S=Segment
I=tuple
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVBNb8IwDL3zK3Kb3brSAtsO1eDEAY4ICYG6HjpoaSXyoTal7Tb46ywlbNqEIsXO83t@jnVnciVHl2z8djkk4n2XsIby8JBK@BSFhDlMYQYraBExUyVrWSGZuqYzWtG0fy4AblIdQuOfdfQYk454jDRH@lO7FvKecFfTURgGPLag81F9Y52WojaJKZSsYAFlIvcpNEguyW/UylKjyPsoNChSEQ9jjOMiY4nsoA3O66D56vxNkPvcsqGlzvquaYPW4Edz9Ub0e8l@u7OyNXXBBif3ksqx4LohrybveMLJCL1CmrSs0m0/LCzBq5HsfXQj1nR0i6qoQnzlJxxkpRJMJCZnhdCqNJ5Dqk7o7j9U2MZGqUP1Cy/GulS7emsGy/Ey3YtUmsF8bGp9SC@9nSTR20XAaYjEbBj1YUjchaELN/AJ45Dp0n4AMrBSxEHEyZ1n4pweXh7iyzc)

Inlined version of the previous answer below. -3 bytes thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen's tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144481/78410).

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + [SymPy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html), 480 bytes

```python
from math import*
from sympy import*
from itertools import*
Q=product
S=Segment
I=tuple
def f(w,h):
 a={1}
 for o in permutations(Q(range(w),range(h))):
  s=[*zip(o,o[1:])]
  if any(x+X-w+1|y+Y-h+1for(x,y),(X,Y)in zip(o,o[::-1]))+any(gcd(x-X,y-Y)>1for(x,y),(X,Y)in s)+any((len({*u,*v})>3)*intersection(S(*u),S(*v))for u,v in Q(s,s))<1:a.add(min(I(D(H(V(x)))for x in o)for H,V,D in Q((lambda p:(w-1-p[0],p[1]),I),(lambda p:(p[0],h-1-p[1]),I),(lambda p:p[::-1],I))))
 return~-len(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU/LbtswELzrK3jLrrQqSrvtQahyyiE@GgYCG4IOrEVZAswHKMqWmqa/7pJWHyhCAhxidmZ3x86@M3p9u7XOKKaE71ivrHE@Te7MMCs7/0/1XjpvzHn4S29L60wzHn2yK3fypKT2yab0oz3LpJEta@FKHRYJE@Urf0tYaxwzrNfMSqdGL3xv9ABbcEKfJFyRlk@HGE1sKKv0e2/BkKl4UWMduL5lQs8wZfv8mvEfc3bIu4yHxjDRjAR7OmAY8MdWFDmvEbPoOR0bmPI9zfkBH99bhkUFZ6nhNR0pvbzh4xrTXofcgzzGZWEH6YgU3gtiTDPSJebZwkAD4ldeiA@iaUD1GjbwBM/wAhMu0ikKzf37TC/0tPjgLNS3RjBbwDXnua0@1mSrsDNtwmr/ivdCd1e8K9olZiDDSZiTfnT6Zx6DCLzFgZpUHFcBpxUSC7COsCK@wGqB3@QnrAtmXQgOLQRraFpxWu5n4pwevjzUt18)

The golfed version takes too long to check the nontrivial answers. The version below has a shortcut in the conditional, so you can check that the results up to `(2,4)` are correct.

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + [SymPy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html), 483 bytes

```python
from math import*
from sympy import*
from itertools import*
Q=product
S=Segment
I=tuple
def f(w,h):
 a={1}
 for o in permutations(Q(range(w),range(h))):
  s=[*zip(o,o[1:])]
  if(any(x+X-w+1|y+Y-h+1for(x,y),(X,Y)in zip(o,o[::-1]))or any(gcd(x-X,y-Y)>1for(x,y),(X,Y)in s)+any((len({*u,*v})>3)*intersection(S(*u),S(*v))for u,v in Q(s,s)))<1:a.add(min(I(D(H(V(x)))for x in o)for H,V,D in Q((lambda p:(w-1-p[0],p[1]),I),(lambda p:(p[0],h-1-p[1]),I),(lambda p:p[::-1],I))))
 return~-len(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU/LbtswELzrK3jLrrQqSrvtQahyyiE@GgYCG4IOrEVZAswHKMqWmqa/7pJWHyhCAhxidmZ3x86@M3p9u7XOKKaE71ivrHE@Te7MMCs7/0/1XjpvzHn4S29L60wzHn2yK3fypKT2yab0oz3LpJEta@FKHRYJE@Urf0tYaxwzrNfMSqdGL3xv9ABbcEKfJFyRlk@HGE1sKKv0e2/BkKl4UWMduL4FoWeYsn1@zfiPOTvkXcZDY5hoRoI9HTAM@GMripzXiGFudJ2ODUz5nub8gI/vTQNmUQVnqeE1HSm9vOHjGtNeh@SDPMZ1YQfpiBTeC2LMM9IlJtrCQEPY@ysvxAfRNKB6DRt4gmd4gQkX7RSV5v59phd6WoxwFupbI5gt4Jrz3FYfa7JVWJs2Ybd/xXuhuyveFe2SNJDhJMxJPzr9M49JBN7iQE0qjquA0wqJBVhHWBFfYLXAb/IT1gWzLiSHFoI1NK04LfczcU4PXx7q2y8)

### Ungolfed, with comments

```python
from math import*
from sympy import*
from itertools import*
def pass_point(p1,p2): # test if the segment passes through another point
 return gcd(p1[0]-p2[0],p1[1]-p2[1]) > 1
def f(w,h):
 pts = [(i,j) for i in range(w) for j in range(h)]
 ans = set()
 for orders in permutations(pts):
  # test if the ordering has 180 degrees rotational symmetry
  if any(x1+x2!=w-1or y1+y2!=h-1for (x1,y1),(x2,y2) in zip(orders, orders[::-1])):continue
  segments = [*zip(orders, orders[1:])]
  # test if a segment passes through another point or two segments intersect
  if any(pass_point(*p)for p in segments)+any(len({*s1,*s2})==4and intersection(Segment(*s1),Segment(*s2))for s1 in segments for s2 in segments):continue
  # take minimum of 8 possible rotations/reflections
  flipH = lambda p:(w-1-p[0],p[1]); flipV = lambda p:(p[0],h-1-p[1]); flipD = lambda p:p[::-1]; nop = lambda p:p
  flipmin = min(tuple(map(lambda o:d(h(v(o))),orders))for h in (flipH,nop)for v in (flipV,nop) for d in (flipD, nop))
  ans.add(flipmin)
 print(len(ans))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVPLbtswELz7K7bohbTpNpTTIlDgnnLovUAuhlAwFiUxFR8gqThq0W93l5TiR9FDIUAUhzO7O7uUG2NnzeZ4bLzVoEXsQGlnfVwuMhJG7cZrSEXpo7V9OMG1bMCJEL47q0wkjjNX0BLeQ5QhgmogdhKCbLU0MRNlQMjboe1AGIunHrJ0AV7GwRto9zWG2d1Ua1fgm@E3z9@8ovAFeE7ZkAPraLkAFwNsYUcUe6bQWA8KlAEvTCvJYUKez0hHqwWmTZIgI6GLTLC@lj4klpNeD1FEZU0gGDpl@MtLJivTQicC8LsbqGXrJbrydhKKPnVOy@hHFKNKmJG88tVr8W57WHPMN/LViJtuzVN2PGMjp4y8FmwsaCrjp3JkKorNxe3Kco3@abm3JiozSAw9dzX7X/5Dwssq2b2oX/zXJFAP8WDP8RHDeHIfz34uRr50NNlwqfA3CV0lUi8N@bUMnC1D8Ztut7fC1Odg2CrybeITJFF23hQ0hwz8MmYeVSiu0ly2A22KHxK0MkoPGmwDd@gnBPXUy9Nwwkcvm37KHlDU9Mp9xQb2Qj/VAlxJcERrl@9dunD3mfF4xcinXaadGA@XDDdN6x6MdVf4nBBLRBjfJA6ul0QLR2aSLWvSkRdiKaVsmuPUiy75JrlchmEz9nLCHjOWO1SfwAeWCqB4ydOV/yDqmszZEXI@zS5NCM8oPSapYTqJd4SzgjLAZZOWgvFpKaZlBm/TssFdVeLviFq62HE2PZ8Y5@xzdfwD)

SymPy has [Geometry module](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/geometry/index.html) that includes an intersection checker `intersection` that works for line segment `Segment` objects. This is much shorter than rolling a hand-written intersection checker based on coordinates. The `intersection` of two `Segment`s is either an empty array (if they don't intersect) or an array that contains a single object (either `Point` or `Segment`, depending on the input).

Comment: In your top and third versions, the `w-1-p[0]` and `h-1-p[1]` can be `w+~p[0]` and `h+~p[1]`, as well as the `x+X-w+1|y+Y-h+1for` to `x-~X-w|y-~Y-h for` (or `x-~X-w|y+Y-h+1for`). ([Relevant tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144481/52210))